# "zoom in" shortcut not working in geany

Tags: 18.04, geany

The "zoom in" shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) is not working in Geany 1.32 on Ubuntu.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it work in other apps such as Firefox?

Comment: yes, it does work in Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the <kbd>+</kbd> provided on Numpad does not work with certain applocations and if you are using the <kbd>+</kbd> provided above the alphabets use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>

The reason for this is + is also used for = :
<kbd>+</kbd> gives =
<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> gives +

Comment: It works. Thanks for the answer, I'm a noob ,really appreciate it :)

Comment: Hey no problem mate, everyone is a newbie at start and there is always something to learn.